# Create A UIViewController Extended Class With A Custom Initializer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I love Swift, except for this

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

If I create any UIViewController extended class I have to have this ugly, unclear, required init, as the init I don't want.

Is there a way I can set up my code so I can have code setup so I can have my own required init, and then it just calls this at the end? I don't want my client code to have to deal with this, and I'd like to have one clear init() call, instead of a 'initWithSomeCumbersomeName()' call.

If anyone has a clean workaround to this I am all ears!